# How to generate database diagram to a PDF in Microsoft visio?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, database-schema, visio, database-diagramming

I am trying to generate database diagram in visio in the folowing way.,

Start--> Microsoft visio -->File-->New-->Template Categories (DataBase and Software) -->Data Base Model Diagram, Now in this .,

View-->Reverse Engineer--> Reverse Engineer Wizard(Microsoft SQL Server)-->My Data Source Name , User , Password (Given Correct Details)

here iam unable to connect to my Data Base,
Both to my User-Server and my Local system database also.,
Iam using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Can any one please help

OR
Can anyone please tell me other way to generate DataBase diagram to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

As Visio could Not Help me out so easily, and i have tried my level and could not work a thing from it, i have tried in other ways..,

http://www.a-pdf.com/image2pdf/index.htm

Here is a link where i have tried to convert IMAGE to PDF and found to be Good with Good Quality too..